# Is it possible to maximize a Finder window without third-party software?

Tags: macos, finder

How can I maximize a window in Finder without using third-party software? I read [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/how-do-you-maximise-windows) but none of these tricks seemed to work.

Comment: Many of those tricks are third-party appellations which would work fine. What problem did you have?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/what-window-management-options-exist-for-os-x

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for native solution, not a third-party..

Answer (score 2):

Move the mouse to the corner of the window where it becomes a resizing arrow and <kbd>option</kbd> double-click to fill the screen.

A double-click on any side or corner will move that side/corner to the edge of the screen. Adding <kbd>option</kbd> will affect the opposite side as well.

Comment: More details: double click on any side to move that side to the edge of the screen, and add option to affect the opposite side as well.

Comment: That is brilliant! All these years and I never knew that! I've added your comment to the answer.

Comment: I have been using Apple computers since the Lisa, and I found the shortcut a couple of days ago on this page: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24091707, but the poster didn't really realize what it could do.

Answer (score 1):

I bought [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) by Many Tricks to solve the Finder's inconsistent zoom behavior. Get it from their website for a free trial and 60-day money-back guarantee. It's been a great solution for me, not just for the Finder problem, but for all my work on a 30-inch Cinema Display.

Comment: It's on the App Store as well, no trial of course. BTW, I personally think Moom is the best of it's genre. You should make it the first one you check out.

Comment: Buy Witch ( http://manytricks.com/witch/ ) while you're there. It finally makes Alt+Tab work properly.

Comment: So there is no way doing this without a third-party application?

Comment: Don't think so, but Moom is really, really good. One of those apps that should just be integrated into the OS.

Comment: This question is asking for a solution without third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app` and turn on the preference: General » "Show Script menu in menu bar"
2. In Terminal, type or copy/paste

   mkdir -p ~/Library/Scripts/Finder

   cd ~/Library/Scripts/Finder

   curl --remote-name http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18414/ase/MaximizeWindow.scpt
3. Go to Finder, open a new (non maximized) window
4. In the menu bar, look for the the "Scripts" item, then look for Finder, and then MaximizeWindow

[image]

Select that, and Voilà!

p.s. - please note that I am not the original author of that AppleScript. I found it at http://olivierfabre.com/shortcut-to-maximize-the-finder-with-applescript and simply tested it and found it worked really well. It appears to be designed with hard-coded values for the screen-size, but if it can't make the window that big, it simply maximizes it.

p.p.s. - the scripts menu isn't all that convenient, but there are ways to assign keyboard shortcuts to them, etc. If you were not averse to 3rd party solutions, I would immediately recommend [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts) and mention that it is free for up to 10 scripts :-)

Comment: The first two links are both broken. Anyway, I posted a similar AppleScript to [How would I make a keyboard shortcut to \*maximize\* the current window?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46233/how-would-i-make-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-maximize-the-current-window).

Comment: The links do not work, please update.