# Is there a shorcut for the 'plus' symbol on every mac window

Tags: macos

On every window, there are 3 buttons colored red, yellow, and green. When you hover over the green, it becomes a plus sign. I want the keyboard shorcut for that. I know that cmd+w seems to be the red one. It does not always work but most often than not, it will close the window. Cmd+H is minimize. What is the third one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign a custom shortcut for the Zoom menu item in System Preferences:

[image]

Or if you want to always maximize windows to fill a screen, see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46233).

Comment: Instead of <Command>-M, which conflicts with the shortcut assigned to Minimize, use something more exotic, like <Command><Option><Control>-M. Needless to say, instead of M you can use a letter of your choice, like Z (for zoom).