# Keyboard Shortcut to maximize a window?

Tags: macos, keyboard, ui, navigation

On Ubuntu to maximize a window we can select the window key and then the up arrow and the window maximizes.

It's also possible to select the window key and side key to pan a window to one side.

Are there any similar shortcuts on MacOS?

Comment: ctrl + command + F ?

Comment: Fullscreen?  Maximize (or zoom) the window?

Comment: The answer is here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372719/maximize-window-shortcut

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximize window shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372719/maximize-window-shortcut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simultaneously holding down the <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> keys maximizes the window.

Re-typing the same keys reverse the process and puts the window back to its original size.

Comment: There is difference between fullscreen and maximized screen in [Apple support documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-apps-in-full-screen-mchl9c21d2be/mac):  'To work in a bigger window without going full screen, maximize (or zoom) the window.'.

Answer (score 3):

There are Apps that allow for this, Rectangle and Magnet come to mind off the top of my head.  There are a few more. I prefer Rectangle over Magnet.

[image]