# Keyboard shortcut to make window fill up screen

Tags: macos, shortcut, productivity

Is there a keyboard shortcut or a way of setting one to fill the window to the whole screen size, without actually being full screened.

There is a way by holding shift and clicking the green plus icon, but I'd prefer a keyboard shortcut for this.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372719/maximize-window-shortcut

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut key… & in fact **Opt**/Green dot doesn't always fill the entire screen; that depends on app & document type, sometimes it only fills vertically.

The way to guarantee it expands to the entire screen area is to Opt/double click any window corner [when the cursor turns to a double arrow].

<sup>(I'm sure this question exists on here somewhere, but my google fu is failing me right now)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way of setting the shortcut key, or do I need a 3rd party app to do this?

Comment: There's no direct shortcut to do this, because it doesn't have a menu item. The other suggestion, Zoom, does just the same as opt/green dot - fills height but not always entire width [this varies per app]

Answer (score 1):

You can change double click behavior on window title through **System Preferences -> Dock & Menu Bar**

This wouldn't solve your problem because you want a keyboard shortcut. So go to **System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts** choose Applications from the list *(it's the last one)* you will see All Applications on right panel.
Click + icon below. A form box will appear.

[image: Screen shot of System Preferences]

**Application** defaults to All Application. *You can choose if you want the shortcut to work only on a specific application.*

The **Menu Title** is the most important one you need to **type Zoom** or if you are using your mac in another language you need to type the option  what's under "Window" -> "Zoom"
*For example I use my mac in Turkish so I need to type Büyüt/Küçült to make the shortcut work.*

Lastly enter your preferred keyboard shortcut by clicking the box and pushing down the keys you want as a shortcut.

[image: Screen shot of Mac menu bar while Safari is open]

I hope it helps, this is my first answer. :)

You can check out Window Management apps on AppStore https://apps.apple.com/en/story/id1519883681?l=en

Comment: Great. Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Zoom does the same as Opt/clicking the green dot… which does not always entirely fill the screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin MacOS only extends the window as needed try shrinking a safari window where some content are not visible then double click or hit zoom from the menu bar it will extend the window just right

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) for free or [Magnet](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=441258766&mt=12) (paid app) which are both very good for organising your windows. Many options and easy to remember their key combos.

[image]