# How to change the default behaviour of the fullscreen/maximize button?

Tags: window-manager, fullscreen, keybindings

[There is a question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139884/make-the-green-full-screen-window-icon-on-yosemite-maximize-windows/151729#151729) that deals with the different behaviour of the fullscreen button in the window bar. There, it is shown that by doing:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + Click on green or outer right icon (plus icon)

I can maximize a window in both width and height to the current screen.

Now I am wondering if I can make this behaviour standard just by clicking the icon. For an extra bonus, I wonder if there is a keyboard shortcut to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I wonder this as well... as of yet I've not found a way to do this.

Comment: Just a heads up, Alt + Click does the equivalent of your Alt + Shift + Click so think the Shift key doesn't need to be pressed?

Comment: @JaiGovindani It's true that not all application behave the same. For most, it seems Alt + Click is enough; yet there are some exception like Google Chrome. There, Alt Click only expands in height but not in width.

Comment: Apple made a bad choice (a long time ago) that really needs to be rectified. Maybe they figure everyone wants to use the kybd and work within conceptual "spaces" (on full screen apps?) but then, why not add a shortcut for full screen/ minimize and moreover, why not just bring back spaces? Now we pretty much have to CMD+TAB to switch between apps. and there's no accessible option for maximizing the window or even going to full screen unless we download some questionable third party app. smh.

Comment: In Mac OS Sierra you can also double click on the window corner(s) to automatically expand them to maximum size, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Spectacle has been discontinued. They recommend using [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle).

---

Use [spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/), a free open source app that has a bunch of handy window management shortcuts.

While it doesn't change the default behavior of the green button, it makes it superfluous for me to do so as I can do everything using keyboard shortcuts without using the mouse.

For full screen, press:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

It also has a bunch of options for 1/2 screen, 1/3 screen, top half, bottom half, etc.

[image: List of all the available options for spectacle to modify the windows]

Comment: Nice find. Spectacle makes me especially happy for also providing the split or snap window feature known from Windows 7.

Comment: Nice find indeed, but sadly "Full Screen" maximizes the window like Microsoft Windows would: using almost *all* screen estate, not using an optimized width and height. (It's indeed what the question asker wanted, and still better than OS X full screen. But I don't want my browsers to use the full screen width; I like the Option-click behavior of the zoom-icon much better, which makes sane applications choose a width that is optimal for its current content. But @k0pernikus is right: the split and snap features are nice.)

Comment: But it doesn't change the *green button* behaviour (like RightZoom did before Yosemite), right?

Comment: I just moved to Mac. I realised I need a lot of third party apps to do basic things that Windows does out of the box.

Comment: And the Mac does a lot of things out of the box that Windows needs 3rd parts apps for.  They are different.

Comment: @Arjan can you tell me what is the MAC version of maximizing window good for? (the one which uses "optimal" width of window) Because it is totaly useless feature in my opinion. Whats worse, it actually makes working with windows much harder because you see the other windows behind. And if theyr both in similar color... your screwed. In my opinion it is something apple wants to be different with at the expense of usability. Not mentioning it acts different in different apps which makes it - what is more then useless? - feature. It makes UI very inconsistent, which is like basic of UX design.

Comment: @user1096901, for example for browsers: any website that boldly use the full browser's width without being nicely responsive will yield loooong lines if zooming a window takes the full screen width. And sites that actually limit the content to some fixed width regardless of the window's width (just like this very website does) will just result in wasting a lot of screen estate (with grey sidebars on this very site). Same for Finder, Pages, ...: I often want a big screen to show *multiple* windows or applications. (As for inconsistent: very much agreed, but I feel it was much better years ago.)

Comment: @Arjan Well you basically want to use some split screen utility which is not primary use of maximizing window function. So you didn't convince me, it is still useless behaviour which is applicable (hardly tbh) in like 5% compared to 95% - that reminds me the 80/20% rule for UX designers. What was the rule name again? Can't recall.

Comment: @user1096901, *"is not primary use of maximizing window function"*, very true, and that's why I'm sorry that Apple changed the green *zoom* thingy into *maximize*, even to full screen with an animation, yuck. What do UX design rules say about such changes? :-) (But luckily most applications I want to zoom now support double clicking their title bar for that zoom, if *"Double-click a window's title bar to minimize"* is disabled.)

Comment: @Arjan I am new to mac so I dont know how it was implemeted before, I hope it changes in new version, this is realy annoying. Closest solution is in Wladimir Palant answer along woth comment about "Maximize Window" but you cant still restore the window back with second click. I think the UX rule says something about implementing the majority of features 80% ppl use with lets say single click and make those other 20% hidden, accessible from for example some kind of menu.

Comment: Wow, is Spectacle fast. It's a change but at least it's a change with some improvement. I've lost the Maximize button forever (or at least until Keyboard Maestro will let me grab it).

Comment: I've managed to speed up Spectacle use by making full screen Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-Up (otherwise unused). This means not you don't have to do any awkward reaching when using the otherwise excellent keyboard shortcuts (left-half, right-half, second-monitor, top-half, bottom-half).

Answer (score 55):

I found that [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) solves this problem nicely (**Note**: BetterTouchTool is no longer free, the trial expires after 45 days). The Preferences aren't quite intuitive:

- Select "Other" category at the top of the window.
- Make sure that "Global" is selected at the left side.
- Click "Configure New Trigger" button in the bottom part of the window.
- Select "Leftclick Green Window Button" as trigger.
- Select "Zoom Window Below Cursor" as predefined action.
- Enjoy!

[image: screenshot]

BetterTouchTool also allows defining a keyboard shortcut for this action (under "Keyboard"). However, the action will still be "Zoom Window Below Cursor" then - it will zoom whichever window your mouse cursor happens to be on, not the currently active window. So this isn't as helpful as it could be unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sure I would not have found this setting without your help. And indeed this perfectly restores the pre-Yosemite behavior. (So: for sane applications not boldly maximizing both height and width, but zooming to the *best* fit. Like for Chrome, often: maximum height and some optimal width that does not use my full screen). Nice find. Annoying full screen be gone! :-)

Comment: Thanks very much. This helped me a lot. However if you want to  maximize the screen, the action "Maximize Window" instead of "Zoom Window Below Cursor" might be a better choice.

Comment: It's better to tie it to "Option+Click" instead.

Comment: @Grocery: Sure, if you use both functions - that's not what was asked in this question however ;)

Comment: Ah! That's better.

Comment: Well this would be nice if it worked for every window. It sadly doesn't. For example for Word app, zoom does nothing. THere are many others. This is totaly MAC feature but should be reconsidered as bug since from UX and usability point of view having same button acting in 3-4 ways is totaly wrong.

Comment: Exactly "Maximize Window" is much better since it behaves in same way for all windows not like "Zoom Window...", which is different for different aps. Still you cant restore window size back with second click once you maximize it.

Comment: @Grocety what do you mean? How can you tie it that way?

Comment: I did have to "save" this option a couple times before it "stuck" - not sure why that was the case. I also created a rule to option-click which will maximize the window (basically, reverse the option- key functionality). The option-click rule apparently needs to appear first in the list for this scheme to work.

Comment: He now has a dedicated app just for this exact functionality. It's  BetterSnapTool on the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 32):

You can go to System Preferences -> Dock
uncheck "Double-click a window's title bar to minimize"
and then, when you double click on the title bar in a window, it will maximize the window without going into full screen mode.

I find it easier than having to hold down the option key and clicking on the green button.

Comment: Doesn't actually maximize in the windows sense. It just resizes to a different annoying size. Damn apple.

Comment: It depends on the app. For most apps, it works just fine. For Chrome and Safari it doesn't maximize, unless you hold down shift!

Comment: @benvolioT use alt/option + shift  and click on green button. quite annoying but does what your expect.

Comment: It's not a question of which app, but of scrollbars. If the window has an horizontal scrollbar, it will stretch horizontally on double click as well. Quite useless in the age of responsive sites.

Comment: ??? On High Sierra, this makes it worse. None of my windows maximize anymore, not even with option click. :(

Comment: It works on most of the apps I've tested it with. I have macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 15):

I tried searching for hidden preference keys from the output of `mdfind kMDItemContentType=public.unix-executable -onlyin /System|xargs strings 2>/dev/null|grep -E '^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{10,80}$'|awk '!a[$0]++'`, but I couldn't find anything.

You can assign a shortcut for the Zoom menu item from System Preferences:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not a bad approach, but it doesn't work for all applications - some don't have a Zoom menu item (Colloquy for example). Also, if the application uses this shortcut for something else you are out of luck, so you better use one that is really unique.

Comment: This is a clean way to do it.

Comment: Sadly it is not (@Wkadunur Oakant explais why) and I am starting to think there is no clean way of doing that. Actually there is no way of doing it, not only the clean one

Answer (score 6):

The question "How do you maximize windows?" was asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2680/how-do-you-maximize-windows?rq=1), and user [Am1rr3za](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/15/am1rr3za) offered the following, which will allow to you to override the default behavior of the maximize button to automatically maximize the window in both width and height:

> Download and use [RightZoom](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30591/right-zoom). It overrides your green plus (zoom) button and works like Windows maximize. You can add it to your login items in your user account to run every time you start OS X.

This software is free *and* it allows for custom key-bindings!

As for having to use <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left-Click to use the maximize feature:

I have noticed that in order to have a screen maximized within the viewport without actually entering "full screen/no distractions" mode in Yosemite, I only need to hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and left-click the maximize button, and that's worked for everything I use on a daily basis: Finder, Chrome, Transmit, SublimeText 3, WebStorm, Outlook, iTerm 2, and even Photoshop CS5(which seems to give me some issues with sizing on my Mac). I don't think you need to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to achieve the screen maximization you're looking for!

Comment: I have tried this app and it does not work as stated in the grey box.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. It works for me just fine so I'm surprised you're having trouble, but I'll see if I can find anything else that'll do the job.

Comment: Fair warning about RightZoom, it's developer also makes key loggers, personally I wouldn't run software from a source like that..

Comment: @Chris Won't really be a problem if you're using Little Snitch or something similar. Also, citation needed.

Comment: As for the app itself, it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: As an aside: if it's exactly *works like Windows maximize* then that is not the previous behaviour. (I don't want to use my full screen width for, say, a browser window, but I do want to grow the window to its optimal size, which often just uses the full height and some optimal width.)

Comment: @Nit citation: follow the link the answer to macupdate, and click on the developer website link. The first product listed on the homepage is a key logger.

Comment: It was a nifty little app, but doesn't work with Yosemite...

Comment: I must warn against RightZoom as it created massive issues in an admittedly old installer and waste a lot of time finding the cause. The only reason for this is is most likely RightZoom hacks the system enough to cause issues. This was the last time I installed any haxies. Better to edit the system yourself and that is easier to remember.

Answer (score 2):

In System Preferences --> Dock: uncheck the option "Double-click a window's title bar to minimize". When you double-click the title bar, it maximizes the window without entering full screen mode.

Comment: Works for some programs, not others.  But this is the best answer I've seen as it doesn't require additional programs.

Answer (score 1):

[ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt) is a free app that does a similar job to some of the others mentioned here: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> gives you full-screen.  It also does quarter screen, center, and move to next screen if you have multiple monitors. It requires [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) which does rather dwarf its <1Mb download. Hadn't come across Spectacle before; it may offer a more complete feature set.

To address another issue mentioned: the accessibility options are under Preferences/Security and Privacy/Accessibility, not the top-level accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of this green button can be changed using a tiny accessibility add-on. Follow the instructions at http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/11/change-the-green-button-maximize-behavior-in-os-x-yosemite-with-bettertouchtool/

Basically, this application (once installed and authorized) with let you enhance the UI of OS X by allowing you to define new behaviours and modify existing ones. This adds for instance the window snapping capability to the Finder and also lets you define new gestures for the Magic Mouse and the Trackpad.

There is one little thing to know though, once you will modify the behaviour of the green button of the OS X window, this will not change the appearance of that button to make it look like a plus (+) instead of a fullscreen icon.

It allows also specifying modifier keys for mouse related action (ex. cmd + left click, ...)

Comment: As an additional information, the recent version of OSX does give the possibility to press Option + Full-Screen to maximize the size of the window without going Full Screen.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the menu bar in Full Screen:

- In **Desktop & Dock** settings, set **Automatically hide and show the menu bar** to "Never"

To change the Full Screen button to Zoom:

- Hold `Option` when you click.

Comment: This does not keep the window header visible like zoom does, but if all you really want is the menu/status bar, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better Touch Tool appears to be the easiest way to fix this.  The newest version of it allows rebinding of the green button.

[Glazblog](http://www.glazman.org/weblog/dotclear/index.php?post/2014/11/26/Yosemite-maximize/fullscreen-button) has a nice article on setting this up.

I also got it to work with RightZoom

Some more details are at [Packetmonger Blog](https://packetmonger.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/fixing-window-zooming-in-os-x-yosemite/)