# How to change zoom/"green button" behaviour

Tags: macos

Since Yosemite, the green button in the upper left corner on each window activates the fullscreen mode. By holding the <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key, it works as before (Mavericks). Is there any possibility (Terminal?) to change this behaviour back to "normal"? For example: holding <kbd>alt</kbd> for fullscreen mode?

**Update**

[You can change the behaviour back to "normal" with BetterTouchTool.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157274/41559)

Comment: Really hope changing it back is possible, inadvertently hitting fullscreen mode is super annoying.

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to change the default behaviour of the fullscreen/maximize button?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151734/how-to-change-the-default-behaviour-of-the-fullscreen-maximize-button)

Comment: Noting that the other question does indeed seem to cover the same functionality, but it is muddier. This one quite precisely covers my exact question.

Comment: @Slevin Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 10):

Hold down Option key and click the Green button. It will change from the Full Screen button back to a Zoom button.

You can also double-click the empty area in the window frame (title bar) if you don’t have it set to minimize when double-clicking.

However, this soft can help you : https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30591/right-zoom

[Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6607235)

Comment: The OP knows about `Option/Alt` way. He asks how to revert it to "normal" (the way it worked on Mavericks) -  maximize without pressing additional key.

Comment: I think that is the only solution. You can't update to Yosemite and change everything because it's not the same than Mavericks or Leopard... There are no sense.

Comment: I agree with @MateuszSzlosek. Besides, the software you suggested does not even solve the OP's problem. You could look at the discussion/feedback in the webpage you linked.

Comment: +1 for this tip "double-click the empty area in the window frame (title bar)". Would still like to see a way to reverse the zoom button behavior. (So Option + Click goes to full screen.)

Comment: Double clicking menu bar in chrome doesn't maximise it

Comment: given how bad the different desktops work together, I'm surprised the dev team wanted people to make use of them.

Comment: Nicola - Chrome's full screen behaviour has always been non-standard.

Answer (score 5):

Double-clicking the empty area in the window frame (title bar) seems like the best answer. In fact a great one, since this is a larger area than the green button..

Worth noting that Firefox wants to hide the title bar – this threw me for a while. Go to 'toolbars>customize' and click on 'title bar' to get it back.

Comment: Note that the double-click behavior can be changed via System Preferences: http://www.cultofmac.com/410346/how-to-maximize-your-el-capitan-windows-without-going-full-screen/

Comment: Now in Firefox, there's some space between the colored dots and the first tab. You can double-click here. You can also double-click the space at the end of the tab bar. So there's no need to enable the standard title bar.

Answer (score 4):

According to what I could find, you cannot change the default behaviour (much like most things in OSX) ... however what I ended up doing is using a keyboard shortcut to use zoom. The following answer helped me do that: https://superuser.com/a/718843/98807

Essentially:

- System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts
- Add a custom "App Shortcut"
- name "Zoom"
- whatever key combo you want e.g.  <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + the green button. This reflects the Windows maximize button behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [page](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/11/change-the-green-button-maximize-behavior-in-os-x-yosemite-with-bettertouchtool/) you can achieve this using BetterTouchTool

1. Download [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/) here
2. Open BetterTouchTool and grant access to “Accessibility” when requested (this will open System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Accessibility)
3. Allow BetterTouchTool access in OS X Preferences
4. Back in BetterTouchTool, click on the “Other” tab in the upper right of the app
5. Select “Global” from the left side options
6. Near the bottom, click on “Configure New Trigger”
7. In the “Trigger” pulldown menu, choose “Leftclick Green Window Button”
8. In the “Predefined Action” menu, choose “Zoom Window Below Cursor”
9. Flip back to the OS X Finder (or another open app) and click the green button, it should now simply maximize the window rather than send it into Full Screen Mode (even if the icon changes to fullscreen when the mouse hovers).
10. Close BetterTouchTool preferences pane (Red Window Button)

The changes will stay in effect as long as you have BetterTouchTool runs in background (its icon should appear in the menu bar, and that it is configured this way.