# Keyboard shortcut to switch between Google Chrome profiles in Mac OS X (10.10 Yosemite)?

Tags: google-chrome, macos

In Mavericks (OS X 10.9), I can simply <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> because it is another window in the same app group, but how can I do it in Yosemite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that it can be done by switching to the adjacent workspace using Ctrl + Left (or Right) arrow.

Update: After I restarted the OS (or maybe created a new user, sorry not sure) I noticed that when I switch to new profiles they are now created under the same app group so I can do again Cmd + tilde.

Update 2: I just discovered that the green maximize icon now in Yosemite will now full screen the app. The shortcut to maximize the length and width of the app window can be found in this question [How to change the default behaviour of the fullscreen/maximize button?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151734/how-to-change-the-default-behaviour-of-the-fullscreen-maximize-button)

> ⌥ + ⇧ + Click on green or outer right icon (plus icon)

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or use arrows to select from multiple users)

[<sub>Source</sub>](https://superuser.com/a/444656/181960)

Comment: Not that if Chrome devtools is open it might toggle mobile / desktop view. Make sure to close devtools first

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> will switch between accounts in Chrome Web browser.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: I do like the brevity. It works

Comment: Saved me HOURS a day.... have one browser for work FULL of work tabs; and another browser with all of my personal tabs/history/addons....

sometimes the windows are minimized and always hiding behind each other....

man this is great...