# How to make fullscreen app's space appear next to the current space?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control

How to make fullscreen app's space appear next to the current space?

Normally it goes to the end of the list of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the fullscreen icon

[image: fullscreen icon]

while pressing the alt key will put it right next to the current desktop, at least on Mavericks.

Comment: on 10.10(yosemite)  there  is no fullscreen icon,  and  alt clicking on the green button (which is now the fullscreen button)  does not work, I also tried cmd-clicking and shift clicking, to no effect

Comment: I see, I didn't have Yosemite available to try at the moment. This answer has some options that may help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151734/how-to-change-the-default-behaviour-of-the-fullscreen-maximize-button

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that, when you make an app window enter fullscreen mode, you want that window to appear next to the current Space (by default it appears at the end of the Spaces list, as you say).

On macOS 11 Big Sur (and possibly older versions), you can do this as follows:

1. Drag the (non-fullscreen) window you want to make fullscreen up to the top of the screen.
2. Mission Control appears. Keep holding the mouse button.
3. The window you're dragging turns into a little thumbnail.
4. In the row of Spaces at the top, drag the thumbnail to the left/right of the Space where you want it to appear. A new space will open up, named after the app you're dragging.
5. Let go of the mouse button to drop the app into that Space in fullscreen mode.

(If you mean, how do you move an *existing* fullscreen app so it's next to another space, then just go into Mission Control and drag the app's thumbnail in the row of Spaces at the top.)

Comment: Strange, this works for for me on **macOS Catalina** but not **macOS Big Sur** .

Comment: @user3439894 That is strange! Works for me on 11.5.2.

Note that it doesn't work for single-window apps (like System Preferences).