# macOS: Is there a way to maximize a window but does not go full-screen?

Tags: macos

I want to expand window of an app in macOS, but I don't want to go into fullscreen mode.

Is this possible somehow by clicking some button?

Oh nvm, I can double click the application bar.. and it expands fully.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the "Zoom" command. It resides in the "Window" menu in an app like Chrome. You can assign a keyboard shortcut to "Zoom" and you will have a quick mouseless command for this.

OR

Move the cursor to any one of the four corners of the Window. When the cursor icon changes to a diagonal bi-directional arrow, press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and double click.

[image: macOS maximize window without taking it full-screen]

This would zoom the window to occupy the entire screen without it entering into full-screen mode.

OR

Double click the application bar

Comment: Great answer and I guess we don't need to hold the Option key.

Comment: @Udhy Without holding the Option key, the window would maximize only in the corresponding direction.

Comment: Holding the options key does not seem to have any affect anymore on macOS 10.15.7. It just maximizes in the corresponding direction. macOS window management.. what a joke

Comment: I've been a Mac user for a bajillion years and I never know the option+double-click trick. Wow. Thanks!

Comment: Macos is a funny OS with a lot of hidden functionality and missing basic requirements :)

Comment: Apple has some of the best hardware (except for the A-cup sized mouse), but macOS is not designed for productivity. It's all about looking flashy, cool and cute. I have to install a bunch of apps to make the window management and clipboard management as productive as it already is in Windows - natively and out of the box. Yes: what a joke!

Answer (score 5):

If you want this consistently, you will need to install a third party utility, like [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com), [Magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com), [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom) or [several others](https://www.producthunt.com/ask/2355-what-s-the-best-window-manager-for-mac).

In some cases you can hold Shift ⇧⃣ while clicking the green stoplight button to have a "cover the whole screen, but don't go into full screen mode" behavior, but this depends on the app.

The reason for this is that historically, macOS had no concept of windows covering the whole screen:

- In classic MacOS the [image: Maximize Widget] widget would make the window change to a size *that is best fitting* the content of the window. This could enlarge or shrink the window. You can check it out using an [online emulation of System 6](https://jamesfriend.com.au/pce-js/system6/).
- MacOS X changed the location and the [appearance of the window widgets](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/archive/reviews/1q00/macos-x-gui/widg-2.jpg) , but the [green stoplight had the same behavior up until OS X 10.9 Mountain Lion](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2000/02/mac-os-x-dp3/5/).
- MacOS X 10.7 Lion [added a zoom widget](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7/4/#full-screen-widget) at the right side of the window that would switch the window into full screen mode and back.
- OS X 10.10 Yosemite [replaced the default behavior of the green stoplight](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/10/os-x-10-10/10/#full-screen) with "full screen". The previous "best fitting size" behavior was moved to two places:

  1. You could press Option ⌥⃣ while clicking on the green stoplight
  2. You could double click the window title

This is the behavior up until macOS 10.16 Catalina, so this is what you are experiencing.

Comment: lol "no concept of windows covering the whole screen", sooo nobody there got the idea that user would stretch app window to the point where it covers whole screen? IMO the full screen mode shouldn't be the default... but this is apple, it just sucks ass

Comment: Is there any terminal command one could run to revert the green button function back to the MacOS X 10.9 and earlier spec?

Comment: @Dave: No, you can use tools or you can choose to use double-clicking on the window itself: [Make the green full screen window icon on Yosemite maximize windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139884/make-the-green-full-screen-window-icon-on-yosemite-maximize-windows)

Answer (score 0):

No, Mac does not allow for maximizing a window without going into the fullscreen mode which means it must exist on its own desktop.

Sure, you can make a window bigger, and some people call that maximizing, but it doesn't hide the menu bar or title bar of the window, and is distracting. The only way to hide the menu bar and window chrome is to use the fullscreen mode, which puts it in a new desktop. Plus,  MacOS also makes you suffer through an animation with delay to get to the fullscreened app.

This is a severe user experience issue that Apple either won't or cannot fix.