# How to get the list of apps running in a Space/Desktop

Tags: macos, applescript, xcode, desktop, spaces

Is there a way to retrieve a list of applications running per Space/Desktop in macOS Big Sur (11.4)? Ideally, I'd like to save the state of apps running in a chosen space and be able to reopen them later in a single space.

Is it possible (using AppleScript or Xcode)? Where to look for Spaces-related data? Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Spaces never did have much documentation, Applescript compatibility or API to speak of, & as no-one's done anything to improve it since the whole world bought laptops & started running everything fullscreen, I don't see as that's going to change. You could just pin apps to Spaces, then they'll always open in the right place - see https://superuser.com/a/1187552/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179403/85275 for some use cases.

Comment: I see. I looked for that in the docs but indeed, couldn't find much. Those use cases are not exactly what I'm looking for but anyway thanks for your help @Tetsujin.

Comment: There are a few window managemnt tools available - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401036/macos-is-there-a-way-to-maximize-a-window-but-does-not-go-full-screen/401042#401042 links a few. Somewhere on here is a list of more, but my google-fu fails me right now.